# How to make this code more DRY?

Tags: c#, dry

Let's say we have these checkboxes:

- FooCheckBox
- BarCheckBox
- BazCheckBox

And these methods:

- Foo
- Bar
- Baz

I want to call each method only if the correponding checkbox is checked. The code might look like this:

```
void DoWork()
{
    if (FooCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        Foo();
        Console.WriteLine("Foo was called");
    }

    if (BarCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        Bar();
        Console.WriteLine("Bar was called");
    }

    if (BazCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        Baz();
        Console.WriteLine("Baz was called");
    }
}
```

Now consider that instead of 3 checkboxes and 3 methods you have a lot more. How would you rewrite the code above to make it more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

Comment: [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for code-improvement questions such as this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say for the case you presented, leave it as is; you don't want to over-abstract without having a good reason, as it can make a code base less maintainable.  Of course context matters though, and it's ultimately a judgement call.

That said, here's how I would approach this.  Create a collection where each item contains both the control and the action delegate.  Then loop through and perform the logic on each item.

```
var items = new KeyValuePair<CheckBox, Action>[] {
    new KeyValuePair<CheckBox,Action>(FooCheckBox, Foo),
    new KeyValuePair<CheckBox,Action>(BarCheckBox, Bar),
    new KeyValuePair<CheckBox,Action>(BazCheckBox, Baz)
};

foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.Key.Checked) 
    {
        item.Value.Invoke();
        Console.WriteLine("Invoked " + item.Value.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

Or (possibly?) better using Linq:

```
items.Where(item => item.Key.Checked).ToList().ForEach(item => new {
    item.Value.Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine("Invoked " + item.Value.Method.Name);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a Dictionary to keep up with what actions refer to which checkboxes.  Then you could do the following:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<CheckBox, Action> kvp in Dict)
{
    if(kvp.Key.Checked)
        kvp.Value.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: `Action` implies no arguments and void as return type.

Comment: @odyodyodys So do the 3 methods proposed by the OP.

Comment: Correct. His Method calls implied no arguments or return types.  Although you could just as easily substitute a Function<T...> in place of the Action if you needed to.

Answer (score 4):

for simplicity I would go with

```
void DoWork()
{
    DoIfChecked(FooCheckBox, Foo, "Foo as Called");
    DoIfChecked(BarCheckBox, Bar, "Bar as Called");
    DoIfChecked(BazCheckBox, Baz, "Baz as Called");
}
void DoIfChecked(CheckBox checkBox, Action action, string message)
{
    if (checkBox.IsChecked)
    {
        action();
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

but you could do something with the message part if it is that simple, and I might throw in some error checking depending on local context.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done in the following way:

```
void DoWork()
{
    Func<Action, string, Tuple<Action, string>> toT = 
        (a, s) => new Tuple<Action, string>(a, s);

    var map = new Dictionary<CheckBox, Tuple<Action, string>>
    {
        {FooCheckBox, toT(Foo, "Foo")},
        {BarCheckBox, toT(Bar, "Bar")},
        {BazCheckBox, toT(Baz, "Baz")},
    };

    foreach (var x in map.Keys)
        if (x.Checked)
        {
            map[x].Item1();
            Console.WriteLine(map[x].Item2 + " was called");
        }
}
```

But I think that sometimes being not very DRY is just ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `Dictionary` with `<CheckBox, Func>` and loop through each value:

```
Dictionary<CheckBox, Func> checkboxes = new Dictionary<CheckBox, Func>();
void Init()
{
    checkboxes.Add(FooCheckBox, Foo);
    checkboxes.Add(BarCheckBox, Bar);
    checkboxes.Add(BazCheckBox, Baz);
}

void DoWork()
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<CheckBox, Func> checkbox in checkboxes)
    {
        if (checkbox.Key.Checked)
        {
            checkbox.Value();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was called", checkbox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```